# RxBinding: different debounced observables within one rx-sequence for RxSearchView?

Tags: android, rx-java2, rx-android, rx-binding

I'm using RxBinding2 to listen for text changes in SearchView. I need to use separate logic with different debounce when user types smth in EditText. I tried this:

```
    RxSearchView.queryTextChanges(searchView)
            .debounce(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) // use debounce 
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(query -> mPresenter.searchRequest(query));
    RxSearchView.queryTextChanges(searchView) // no debounce required here
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(query -> mPresenter.updateUI(query));
```

RxSearchView.queryTextChanges overrides listener, so, of course, only second being called.

May I combine  these two calls *searchRequest* and *updateUI* with different debounces into one rx-sequence?
Should I use filter operator in someway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this in many ways, but I think the cheapest way would be to use the `.share()` operator. This operator is a shorthand for `.publish().refCount()`. So you could do something like this.

```
Observable<String> sharedTextChanges = RxSearchView.queryTextChages(searchViw).share()

sharedTextChanges
            .debounce(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) // use debounce 
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(query -> mPresenter.searchRequest(query));

sharedTextChanges
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(query -> mPresenter.updateUI(query));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Works exactly as I wanted! Thanks a lot!